# Laravel login directing to auth/login but I have not set it up

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Have a login and registration system using the normal L5 auth controller etc.

Registration works, but when logging in I get a:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Error.

My routes are set up as so:

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

And my form opening:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/login">
```

But its still trying to go to auth/login. Have searched all the code but no idea where its trying to do this?

The validation works perfectly fine and throws errors but just wont process correctly.

Comment: Change your route to this: `Route::post('/post-login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');`

Comment: Worked, whats the reason?

Comment: It's because the route is confused of the url you're looking for.